# How to replace punctuation with HTML entities

Tags: python, string, ascii

I would like to replace sections of punctuation in a string such  as `,'".<>?;:` with the corresponding HTML entities, `&#44;&#39;&#34;&#60;&#62;&#59;&#58;`. So far I've looked into using the `string` library with `.maketrans` and `string.punctuation`. It seems that you can convert `ascii` to `string` (but not the other way round. Based on what I've found thus far). Preferrably after a solution that I don't need to write RegEx (trying to not reinvent the wheel).

Comment: These are called HTML entities, not ASCII.  The punctuation marks listed (`,'",<>?;:`) *are* ASCII characters.

Comment: I've posted an answer. What do you think of it, please ?

Comment: Yeah I liked it, +1 rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it yourself converting each character separately.

For example:

```
def htmlentities(string):
  def char_htmlentities(c):
    return '&#%d;' % ord(c) if c in html_symbols else c

  html_symbols =  set(',\'".<>?;:')
  return ''.join(map(char_htmlentities, string))
```

UPD: I rewrote the solution to be linear instead of quadratic in time complexity

Comment: I'm getting `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2212' in position 629: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Which version of python do you run? And please upload a file somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure but it could be a reason - there is no good unicode support in python below 3 versions branch

Comment: I wouldn't say that there's no good unicode support in 2.x.  It takes a little care, and Python 3 forces you to think about it in the ways you should be anyway, but if you do use a little care it works fine.  That said, this works fine for me (modulo the forgotten closing `;`) with an input string containing `u'\u2212'` and some punctuation, encoded or not.

Comment: Character entity references end with a `;` - you need it after appending `ord(c)`.  I'd just write the return value as `'&#%d;' % ord(c)`, personally, but if I didn't do that `'&#' + str(ord(c)) + ';'`

Answer (score 1):

The regex solution will probably be the simplest, since you can just use a single call to `re.sub()`.

```
import re
def htmlentities(s):
    return re.sub('[,\'".<>?;:]',
                  lambda m: return '#%d;' % m.group(0),
                  s)
```

Comment: I'm getting a `SyntaxError` for `lambda m: return '#%d;' %m.group(0),` on `n`.

Answer (score 1):

sasha's code has two drawbacks in my opinion:

- each time `char_htmlentities()` is called on a character in `map(char_htmlentities,string)`, it does the following actions: test `if c in html_symbols`, compute `ord(c)`, compute `&#%d;' % ord(c)`
- each time `htmlentities()` is called on a new string, the function `char_htmlentities()` is created again.

A way to do better is to create a dictionary and to make it a default value of `htmlentities()` , as the following code:

```
import re

punct = ',\'".<>?;:'

def changing(m, d=dict((c,'&#%d;' % ord(c)) for c in punct)):
    return d[m.group()]
regx = re.compile('[%s]' % punct)

susu = 'hg! ab,sd, opo> godo; sza: popo.'
print susu
print regx.sub(changing,susu)
```